# Why does a second parameter cause this script to fail?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have three bat files in Windows 7

1) main.bat:

```
test testEcho parm1 parm2
```

2) test.bat:

```
@echo With one parm
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -nologo -noprofile ^
  -executionpolicy bypass -command "& {start-process -verb 'runas' -file %1.bat %2}"

@echo With two parms
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -nologo -noprofile ^
  -executionpolicy bypass -command "& {start-process -verb 'runas' -file %1.bat %2 %3}"

pause
```

3) testEcho.bat:

```
@echo ==== 0:%0 1:%1 2:%2
pause
```

When I run main.bat, it passes the name of the target bat file (testEcho) and two parameters.  Then I use PowerShell twice to run the passed in bat file name (%1 = testEcho).  The first time is with one parameter (%2 = parm1) and the second time with two parameters (%2 = parm1, %3 = parm2).

The first time works as expected, running testEcho.bat with one parameter. It echos the result:

```
==== 0:C:\testEcho.bat 1:parm1 2:
```

The second run fails with error:

```
"Start-Process: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts 
  argument 'parm2'.At line:1 char:4"
```

Why does the second attempt fail and how can I get it to work?  The only difference between them is that the first attempt passes only one parameter and the second attempt passes more than one parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify an ArgumentList in order to use multiple arguments. These arguments need to be delimited by commas. http://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html

```
@echo With one parm
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -nologo -noprofile ^
  -executionpolicy bypass -command "& {start-process -verb 'runas' -file %1.bat %2}"

@echo With two parms
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -nologo -noprofile ^
  -executionpolicy bypass -command "& {start-process -verb 'runas' -file %1.bat -ArgumentList %2, %3}"

pause
```